# release ABMultiValueRef object

Tags: iphone, memory-management

In my app, static analyser points a leak in the following code:

```
ABMultiValueRef phone = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,  kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString *mobilephone= (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex (phone,0);
```

similarly whenever i use this function ABRecordCopyValue it points a leak

I tried to release it by `[phone release];` method, however I am getting a compiler warning "invalid receiver type 'abmultivalueref'". What is the proper way to release this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing the `NS` data types with the `CF` data types.  The address book methods typically return core foundation (`CF`) objects.  These objects are toll-free bridged, which means they can be used interchangeably with `NS` types.

When using core foundation objects, any method with 'copy' in its name will return an object that you later need to release using `CFRelease`.  Only if you cast it to its `NS` equivalent can you use `- release`.

So your code could be written as either of the following:

```
ABMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString *mobilephone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, 0);

// other code

[mobilephone release];
```

or

```
ABMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
CFStringRef mobilephone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, 0);

// other code

CFRelease(mobilephone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `CFRelease(phone);` ? 
Because `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` is not a NSString, it's a `CFStringRef`

Answer (score 1):

Using `__bridge_transfer` ensures that ARC will release the object for you. 
Using `__bridge` means you must release the returned object manually.