# how to solve object leaked in addressbook

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
  ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge  ABRecordRef)([arrTemp1 objectAtIndex:i]),
                                                                 kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
                    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
                    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
                } else
                {
                    phone = @"[None]";
                }
```

after this line of code i am getting "Object leaked : object allocated and stored into 'phoneNumber' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1". I saw several similar posts but didn't get the exact solution for my question. Due to this leaks my app crashes. So anyone know this please help me

Comment: phoneNumbers is used anywhere?after this loc

Comment: yes will show u entire code     ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge  ABRecordRef)([arrTemp1 objectAtIndex:i]),
                                                                 kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
                    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
                    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
                } else
                {
                    phone = @"[None]";
                }

Comment: Please add this to the Question ..Edit is  available on the bottom of the Qn

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge  ABRecordRef)([arrTemp1 objectAtIndex:i]),kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
      phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
} else {
      phone = @"[None]";
}

CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: when use this code get "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"...

Comment: Which line? I am using a windows machine so I can not debug the code

Answer (score 0):

As these objects are CoreFoundation Objects , you should use CFRelease to release the memory being occupied. You must use `CFRelease(phoneNumbers); .` Checkout the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308994/release-abmultivalueref-object) to release the memory occupied by ABMultiValueRef objects.